# Stopped block production / aura

Tags: block-production

Error with `block` built on

`0xxxx: ClientImport("A pending forced authority set change could not be applied since it must be applied after the pending standard change at #xx")`

Block production and also finalization stopped, in txpool I found sudo call, and remove it via `author_removeExtrinsic`, but block production not fixed

UPD:

There were 2 validators in the network and I wanted to add a third one using `validatorSet.addValidator()`. However, I mistakenly executed `validatorSet.forceRotateSession()`.

Prior to that, I also executed `grandpa.NoteStalled()` because finalization had stopped.

After this, `validatorSet.forceRotateSession()` took a very long time and the transaction did not go through, getting stuck in the queue. Now everything has stopped, including block production and finalization.

LOG:

```
2023-07-02 16:24:58.689  INFO tokio-runtime-worker sc_basic_authorship::basic_authorship:  Starting consensus session on top of parent 0x7a4e64085afc435b04e366871435ad7c394c09f730a19caaf31d7da2645a6813
2023-07-02 16:24:58.715  INFO tokio-runtime-worker sc_basic_authorship::basic_authorship:  Prepared block for proposing at 9690000 [hash: 0xdbb7c1026537c7ded7a69b878ebec1570dd0d7d9a151673bf75ba76555fd957b; parent_hash: 0x7a4e…6813; extrinsics (3): [0x105c…49a3, 0x0e90…8485, 0xaf9f…8ed2]]
2023-07-02 16:24:58.716  INFO tokio-runtime-worker aura:  Pre-sealed block for proposal at 9690000. Hash now 0x5628567644e59458cba37accf115ffa14c7b2df8cff0f46da8f1f49afeb21379, previously 0xdbb7c1026537c7ded7a69b878ebec1570dd0d7d9a151673bf75ba76555fd957b.
2023-07-02 16:24:58.717  INFO tokio-runtime-worker afg: Not applying authority set change forced at block #9689995, due to pending standard change at block #9689962
2023-07-02 16:24:58.717  WARN tokio-runtime-worker aura: Error with block built on 0x7a4e64085afc435b04e366871435ad7c394c09f730a19caaf31d7da2645a6813: ClientImport("A pending forced authority set change could not be applied since it must be applied after the pending standard change at #9689962")
2023-07-02 16:25:03.149  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate:  Idle (1 peers), best: #9689999 (0x7a4e…6813), finalized #9689961 (0x4b87…a82f), ⬇ 83 B/s ⬆ 0.7kiB/s
```

Comment: Happened after calling 2 sudo calls

Comment: NFO tokio-runtime-worker afg: Not applying authority set change forced at block #xx, due to pending standard change at block #xx

Comment: Can you update your question and tell how to reproduce the error?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have bricked your network by sending a wrong `noteStalled`. You need to restart the chain.

Comment: Do you mean restart nodes? Or something different?

Comment: I already restarted the whole network, I still get the error